# How to import a csv into c-tree

Tags: c#, sql, c-treeace

I am using ctreeACE to create a local database, and I was given a csv file that contains 1000 entries of data and wanted to know if there was a way to import it without hard coding it?

Right now I am having to insert line by line with:

```
INSERT INTO testdata VALUES 
('1ZE83A545192635139','2018-06-19 00:00:00',etc)
```

Note that ctreeACE only allows single row inserts with `INSERT...VALUES` ([Source](https://docs.faircom.com/doc/esql/32284.htm))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a way to do this directly, but you could use [this tool](http://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-sql.htm) to create your insert statements.

First input your data.  You can load the csv directly, I just hardcoded two sample lines:

[image]

Next set your input options as needed.  I used comma separators and `'` as a quoting character in the example:

[image]

Third, set your output options.  This would be a huge screenshot and is pretty self-explanatory so I'm leaving it out.

Last, click `CSV to SQL Insert`, and it will generate formatted insert statements (one line per insert) for you:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: That certainly did help! thank you! that made things way easier for me!

Comment: @BartholomewAllen Happy to help :)